# How to remove removed datanode details from hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I used following property for reduce dead node timeout.

```
Propertyname : dfs.heartbeat.recheck.interval
value        : 1
```

But when I remove datanode from cluster this details not removed from hadoop cluster.It is in dead node state only in that cluster.

Please suggest any way to remove removed datanode details from hadoop cluster.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the dead datanodes information actually? It will be there to know about the dead datanode details. What you are trying to achieve with that?

Comment: When i use the existing cluster that time removed nodes in original cluster also appeared in dead state.i can't remove removed node details from cluster.This removed node details present in cluster as deadstate.I'm using following command for view this details.hadoop dfsadmin -report.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the live nodes or dead nodes alone by using the below HDFS commands

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report -live
hdfs dfsadmin -report -dead
```

You can get the live node name or any other particular details using the below HDFS command

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report -live | grep Name:
```

Hope it helps.